# How can i change the indentationGuides symbols in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

Is actually possible to change the indentation guide symbols in Visual Studio Code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as of VSCode 1.16. The feature request is tracked here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29634

You can currently change the color of these symbols however by setting `editorWhitespace.foreground`

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorWhitespace.foreground": "#f0f"
},
```